# Recovering a deleted photo on iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos

I have a 32GB iPhone 4 version 4.0.1. I have many photos on my phone, but I have deleted an important photo from my iPhone. How can I get this photo back from my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have synced your iPhone and thus have your photo somewhere in your computer, or uploaded it to some service you can't recover it **easily**.

Most likely you don't have any copies of it and you'll have to find some professional to recover it from the iPhone memory. Maybe, and I say really just maybe, apple care support would be able to do it.

Here's one thing you could try, though: manage to get access to iPhone file system somehow (jailbreak, [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), anything you want) and get some [file recovery software](http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software). Keep in mind *recovering deleted files* are complicated and **expensive business**. You'll only be able to do it this way if you get lucky.

Comment: Apple Care doesn't do data recovery but they may be able to recommend a place that can.